# Is it Possibile to wake up a Deep sleep BLE device in Android SDK?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have some BLE beacons that go on deep sleep mode for saving battery policy.
Is it possibile, in Android SDK, directly connect (or simply discover) these beacons and wake them up? I need just their presence and Signal Strength.

Comment: What beacons do you use? If the radio is possibly turned off in deep sleep, then how do you think you could reach them over the air?

Comment: Depending on the beacons you have, some of them keep their connection acknowledging the link which have an interval from milliseconds up to 4 seconds, and between those connections they goes to sleep mode. For that reason you should be able to connect with them later on. If that's not the case and they don't come back turning on the radio, there is no possibility to do anything with them via OTA.

Comment: I'm using StickNFind stickers and their SDK, do you know them?

Answer (score 8):

If a BLE device is in deep sleep, that usually means its radio is completely shut down, since the radio usually is a very current consuming part.

For a Central device (phone) to discover, and/or being able to connect to a Peripheral (a tag), the Peripheral has got to be advertising. Advertising here means to be sending (small) radio packets once in a while, which the Central device will listen for. Receiving such packets can then be used as a indicator for whatever phone app is running that the tag is nearby, and by checking the RSSI (possible on multiple advertisements), an estimation of distance can be made. You can take a look at this picture (taken from [here](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/index.php/what-is-the-minimum-time-for-a-app-and-a-peripheral-to-create-a-connection)), to better understand how advertising and scanning works in BLE:

[image: Advertising and scanning in BLE]

If the tag is sleeping in a mode in which it doesn't send such advertisement packets, there is no way to wake it up over the air.

Comment: Can't see how the image relates to the OPs question. If I may add up, it's up to the firmware if it's built with wake up trigger.