# how to wake up devices using BLE? What profile both devices has to have to make this happen?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have two BLE enabled devices. To save power, one device goes to sleep mode. Now when needed, how my another device which is already awake, can i use BLE to wake up another device? What are different BLE profiles would i need on both devices to have to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific BLE profile for waking up a device. I assume that BLE is turned off if your device is sleeping, so there would be no way of sending a command since the radio can't hear them. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097079/is-it-possibile-to-wake-up-a-deep-sleep-ble-device-in-android-sdk) answer as well.

You should wake up the device yourself and start advertising for some time. If no device connects go to sleep again. If you do this once every minute the other device has to wait a maximum of one minute to connect. This would be the right way to do this in BLE.